# Display a Page and Edit/Update the page using popup Dialog

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, popup

I display the content of my db on a table, however, I would like the user to be able "edit/update" the content using a popup with the help of Jquery. However, I've been struggling with getting the edit_id to be displayed inside the popup. Note: I don't want to edit the table on a new page.
Below is my script for popup:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#page-help').each(function() {
        var $link = $(this);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .load($link.attr('href') + ' #content')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: $link.attr('title'),
                width: 600,
                height: 400
            });

        $link.click(function() {
            $dialog.dialog('open');

            return false;
        });
    });
}); 
</script>
```

When the below link is Click:

```
<body>
 <a id="page-help" href="edit_data.php?edit_id=<?php print($row['atm_id']); ?>" >Edit?</a></body>
```

[SnapShoot of Display Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZclA.png)

Pls Kindly help. I just want to be able to edit/delele my table content using popup dialog instead of opening on a new page.

Comment: I will appreciate, if you know any tutorial that can help, though I ve read many but none really met up, most of it major on the JavaScript aspect without talking about getting the info from the db and URL. Or if you can help modified this : http://atomicrobotdesign.com/blog/web-development/using-ajax-and-php-to-get-content-from-a-database/

Answer (score 0):

you should use preventDefault() function to avoid redirecting to other page

i.e  try this code instead

```
       $link.click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $dialog.dialog('open');

            return false;
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, however, the problem in still unresolved. Note If I change the href="edit_data.php?edit_id=<?php print($row['atm_id']);?>"     to      href="home.php". The home page is been loaded into the dialog, I know the issue is about using ajax/jqeury get() function. But I dont know how to make it work. I can send my sccript to your email If need be. I've been struggling with this for like 3days. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using this:

```
href="edit_data.php?edit_id=<?php print($row['atm_id']); ?>"
```

You need to echo the value and not print it.

Change this to:

```
href="edit_data.php?edit_id=<?php echo $row['atm_id']; ?>"
```

And where is coming the '#content' from? Is this an anchor tag you are appending to the URL?

If you post the HTML will be helpfull in order to spot the problem.